# Hibernate 6.4.1.Final generates incorrect SQL (MS-SQL) for @JoinTable

Tags: hibernate

Hello StackOverflow Community,

### Attempted:

Upgrading Spring Boot from 2.7.5 to 3.2.1, which uses Hibernate ORM core version 6.4.1 Final.

Using Java 21

#### Entity

Person.java

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(schema = "lotr", name = "person")
public class Person {

    @Id
    String person;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "lotr.person_appanage", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "person") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "appanage") })
    List<Appanage> appanages;

}
```

Appanage.java

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(schema = "lotr", name = "appanage")
public class Appanage {

    @Id
    String appanage;

    String description;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "region")
    Region region;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "lotr.person_appanage", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "appanage") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "person") })
    List<Person> personnels;

}
```

Region.java

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(schema = "lotr", name = "region")
public class Region {

    @Id
    String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "region")
    List<Appanage> appanages;

}
```

#### Repository

PersonRepository.java

```
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, String> {

}
```

#### SQL

```
CREATE SCHEMA lotr;

CREATE TABLE lotr.region (
    name varchar(255) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK__region__72E12F1A63319616 PRIMARY KEY (name)
);

CREATE TABLE lotr.appanage (
    appanage varchar(255) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    description varchar(255) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    region varchar(255) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK__appanage__4F3CC6682430EE11 PRIMARY KEY (appanage),
    CONSTRAINT FK1ouxx29rdxdweras7xk5dvq3n FOREIGN KEY (region) REFERENCES lotr.region(name)
);

CREATE TABLE lotr.person (
    person varchar(255) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK__person__46D1A7F9CCE10CE3 PRIMARY KEY (person)
);

CREATE TABLE lotr.person_appanage (
    appanage varchar(255) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    person varchar(255) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FKa305os45jdiwpi5cdmxgfscop FOREIGN KEY (person) REFERENCES lotr.person(person),
    CONSTRAINT FKferbms7vr9sno17hovaj09ehx FOREIGN KEY (appanage) REFERENCES lotr.appanage(appanage)
);

INSERT INTO lotr.region (name) VALUES (N'Shire');
INSERT INTO lotr.appanage (appanage,description,region) VALUES (N'Bag End',N'Burrow',N'Shire');
INSERT INTO lotr.person (person) VALUES (N'Frodo Baggins');
INSERT INTO lotr.person_appanage (appanage,person) VALUES (N'Bag End',N'Frodo Baggins');
```

#### Unit Test

```
@Test
void test() {
    logger. Debug("-- " + personRepo.getReferenceById("Frodo Baggins").getAppanages());
}
```

#### Config

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=?
spring.datasource.username=?
spring.datasource.password=?

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true

#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create

spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl

#logging.level.?=DEBUG

logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
```

#### Maven

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

### Issue:

```
org.hibernate.SQL                        : select a1_0.person,a1_1.appanage,a1_1.description,r1_0.name from [lotr.person_appanage] a1_0 join lotr.appanage a1_1 on a1_1.appanage=a1_0.appanage left join lotr.region r1_0 on r1_0.name=a1_1.region where a1_0.person=?
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 208, SQLState: S0002
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Invalid object name 'lotr.person_appanage'.
```

Square brackets are created on the @JoinTable name 'lotr.person_appanage'.

#### Question:

What is the fix/alternatives for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the (schema = "lotr") attribute on the @JoinTable instead of the name attribute fixed the issue

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(schema = "lotr", name = "person_appanage", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "person") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "appanage") })
List<Appanage> appanages;
```